# Latex listofsymbols\\ \newsym with \Theta error

Tags: overleaf

I am working with Overleaf on a university assignment, which requires an overview of all mathematical symbols with description and unit. Therefore, I tried using a listofsymbols but when I put a Greek symbol via `\Theta` it's throwing an error. (I am using pdfLaTeX compiler)
package:

```
\usepackage[final]{listofsymbols}
```

document:

```
\opensymdef
\newsym[True anomaly $(\degree)$]  {trueanomaly}{\Theta}
\closesymdef
```

Is giving me a red error

> \MT@res@a has an extra

and inline there is written

> \Theta must be in math mode.

But when I surround it with `$` it gives even more errors.

Nevertheless, when I use the

```
§ \trueanomaly = 1 $
```

later in my writing, it correctly shows the symbol in my equation. But it does not show the symbol in the listofsymbols.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Currently your question is a bit unclear. The commands that you mention are not standard LaTeX commands (it looks a bit like ConTeXt, but also not really) so probably you are using a package or some kind of template that defines these commands. Could you add a small complete document to your question that allows to reproduce the problem? If you indeed use a custom template then a link to the source of that template would be useful as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried to edit my question to provide additional information. Tomorrow I will try to add a reproducible document.

Comment: Maybe is there a completely different approach or package which can be used as a mathematical list of symbols?

Comment: I can't reproduce your exact issue (using pdflatex from TeX Live 2019) but there seems to be some kind of incompatibility between `\degree` and the `listofsymbols` package. The package is from 2003 so some problems are expected. However, on my system the alternative `\newsym[True anomaly $({}^\circ)$]{trueanomaly}{\Theta}` works without issues.

Comment: ahhh thanks! you are right, the error was not induced by the \Theta but by the \degree, I still get red markings around all my \"greek" in the symbol list, but this might be due to overleaf, since there is no compiler error.

Comment: If you would write as an answer I can accept it. :)

Comment: How are you defining `\degree`? It's not defined by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be some kind of incompatibility between `\degree` and the `listofsymbols` package. Using `{}^\circ` (a circle superscript without preceding symbol) does work (and looks the same as `\degree` from the `gensymb` package).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[final]{listofsymbols}
\opensymdef
\newsym[True anomaly $({}^\circ)$]{trueanomaly}{\Theta}
\closesymdef
\begin{document}
$\trueanomaly = 1$
\listofsymbols
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what definition of `\degree` you're using, because it's not a standard command.

On the other hand, this works as expected

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[final]{listofsymbols}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\robustify\textdegree

\opensymdef
\newsym[True anomaly (\textdegree)]{trueanomaly}{\Theta}
\closesymdef

\begin{document}

$\trueanomaly = 1$
\listofsymbols

\end{document}
```

[image]